# SQL Server: Get data from record with max date / newest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select, max

I am using the following stored procedure to get the newest date out of a column which works fine.

Can someone tell me how I have to amend this that I also get the rest of the data of this record selected (i.e. the one with the max date) ?
The column in question is called "updated" and is formatted as datetime so the values there should be unique.

**Example:** 
The max value for column "updated" is the row with "itemID" = 3. 
In this case I also want the rest of the data in this row selected, say the columns are called col1, col2, col3, col4 + the column "updated".

**My stored procedure:**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT      CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), MAX(updated), 106) AS lastUpdated
FROM        MeetingDetails
WHERE       itemStatus = 'active'
FOR XML PATH('updates'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('root')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the analytic approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3 
                            ORDER BY updated DESC) AS rk
        FROM   MeetingDetails
        WHERE  itemstatus = 'active') t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: Due to your partitioning, this query will select the **oldest** row for **every combination of `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`**.

Comment: switched `ASC` with `DESC` by mistake. Fixed.

Comment: You are also missing the `OVER` keyword and you are not selecting updated` in your subquery.

Comment: I am really not at my best today :-( Thanks @JonSenchyna

Comment: You are also not filtering out rows where `itemStatus <> 'active'`.

Comment: @Mureinik Happens to the best of us.  @user2571510 isn't either as they selected your answer without checking that it worked for them first ;)  As a final edit, I think you'll want to remove the `PARTITION BY` clause to get the results they're looking for (at least from my understanding, they only wanted the most recent row from the table).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, updated
FROM   MeetingDetails 
WHERE  updated in (
    SELECT      MAX(updated)
    FROM        MeetingDetails
    WHERE       itemStatus = 'active'
)
```

This should be what you're looking for. From here, if you need to narrow it down further, just add more criteria to your where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query:

```
set nocount on;

select 
   md.col1, 
   md.col2,
   -- ......
   convert(varchar(11), md.updated, 106) as lastUpdated
from
   MeetingDetails md
where
   md.itemStatus = 'active'
   and md.updated = (select max(updated)
                     from MeetingDetails
                     where itemStatus = 'active')
for xml path('updates'), elements, type, root('root')
```

Based on how many records have the max(updated) this select may return more than one row and hence this query could return multiple nodes.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `TOP 1` clause with an `ORDER BY` should work for you.

```
SELECT TOP 1 col1, col2, col3, col4,
       updated
FROM   @MeetingDetails 
WHERE  itemStatus = 'active'
ORDER BY
      updated DESC
FOR XML PATH('updates'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('root')
```