# Use MSSQL GROUP BY with too many columns

Tags: php, sql-server

How can I use *Group By* to my **LOCATION** column on my query which is having I think an aggregate things?

```
SELECT a.[PlateNo]
,a.[TrxDate] as DATES
,a.[Location] ,a.[account]
,a.[TrxTime]
,a.[Msg]
,b.company FROM [Mark_Fast].[dbo].[Alarm] a
inner join [Mark_Fast].[dbo].[account] b 
on a.[account] = b.senderno or a.[account] = b.sim1 
where a.trxdate BETWEEN '09/10/2015' AND '09/10/2015' and Msg LIKE '%geo%' 
and (a.PlateNo = 'BCY536') ORDER BY Location desc
```

The sample output is:

```
PlateNo  Dates    Location   account   TrxTime          Msg             company
123     9/9/1999   Loc 1      321      02:39:00  Geozone Exit Alert!    Transpartner Trucking Services
123     9/9/1999   Loc 1      321      02:39:00  Geozone Exit Alert!    Transpartner Trucking Services
123     9/9/1999   Loc 1      321      02:31:00  Geozone Entry Alert!   Transpartner Trucking Services
123     9/9/1999   Loc 3      321      02:32:00  Geozone Exit Alert!    Transpartner Trucking Services
123     9/9/1999   Loc 3      321      02:33:00  Geozone Exit Alert!    Transpartner Trucking Services
123     9/9/1999   Loc 1      321      02:34:00  Geozone Entry Alert!   Transpartner Trucking Services
123     9/9/1999   Loc 2      321      02:35:00  Geozone Exit Alert!    Transpartner Trucking Services
123     9/9/1999   Loc 2      321      02:37:00  Geozone Entry Alert!   Transpartner Trucking Services
```

I want the output to be Group by *Location* but I don't know how to execute it in my query. What am I trying to achieve is to have an output that looks like this:

```
PlateNo  Dates    Location   account   TrxTime          Msg             company
        123     9/9/1999   Loc 1      321      02:39:00  Geozone Exit Alert!    Transpartner Trucking Services
        123     9/9/1999   Loc 2      321      02:39:00  Geozone Exit Alert!    Transpartner Trucking Services
        123     9/9/1999   Loc 3      321      02:31:00  Geozone Exit Alert! Transpartner Trucking Services
```

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: have you tried writing "mssql group by" in the google box and check the first entry?

Comment: This sample output does not seem grouped in any way. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas My expected output would be a 1 Loc 1 and 1 loc 3 and1 loc 2 row only

Comment: What do you want to do with `TrxTime`? Most of them are different for each Loc.

Comment: I want to output the latest `TrxTime`@EvaldasBuinauskas because the main goal of the query is to show the difference of `TrxTime` of `Geozone Entry` and `TrxTime` of `Geozone Exit`

Comment: You have three different TrxTime for Local 1 then how you perform the group by clause. Do you want top 1 of TrxTime for local 1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Get data from record with max date / newest date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911553/sql-server-get-data-from-record-with-max-date-newest-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see aggregate  of accounts group by location you'll have to add following to your query.

```
GROUP BY a.Location HAVING sum(a.accounts)
```

If you can give sample of expected output with all column heads you may get a better answer.

For latest TrxTime you need to add following lines to your query

```
GROUP BY a.Location HAVING max(a.TrxTime)
```

Comment: This is not what i need you can see the expected output scroll up.

Comment: Your question was incomplete that's why I gave you a general reply that you can work on. Now I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

try to use aggregate function MAX():

`SELECT a.[PlateNo],
    a.[TrxDate] as DATES,
    a.[Location],
    a.[account],
    MAX(a.[TrxTime]),
    a.[Msg],
    b.company 
FROM [Mark_Fast].[dbo].[Alarm] a
INNER JOIN [Mark_Fast].[dbo].[account] b ON a.[account] = b.senderno or a.[account] = b.sim1
WHERE a.trxdate BETWEEN '09/10/2015' AND '09/10/2015' AND Msg LIKE '%geo%'
      AND (a.PlateNo = 'BCY536')
GROUP BY a.[PlateNo],a.[TrxDate],a.[Location],a.[account],a.[Msg],b.company`

Answer (score 0):

Grouping only by Location will not because other columns have different data.

Therefore you will have to add more columns to show the records uniquely.
GROUP BY [Location], [TrxDate], [TrxTime], [Msg]